# Native PHP 5.6 OpenSSL Composer.phar failed to enable crypto on Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, server, windows-server, php-openssl

I have a problem with PHP 5.6 native on a Windows machine. I get this error when I try to run a composer update (php composer.phar update):

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

The openssl extension is loaded. I already downloaded this file `http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` and saved it to a path on my machine and set this path in the php.ini like

`openssl.cafile = "c:\path\to\cacert.pem"`

But it didn't work, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved: I had to remove https-proxy from system variables. Don't know why, but it works...

Comment: How did you remove https-proxy?

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command without 'sudo' :

> composer update