# Composer in Windows 10 without WAMP

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I am looking to install [Laravel/Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead) on my Win 10 x64 box but I cannot seem to get [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) to install. I am not using WAMP by the way which seem to be the only examples of this problem I have found.

First step completed was install [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html).

Second step is installing Composer, which asks to be pointed to `php.exe`. I downloaded [VC11 x86 Thread Safe (2015-Sep-04 02:29:46)](http://windows.php.net/download/) from php for Windows. I then extracted this package to `d:\php`. There was no installation process per se.

I then edited both `php-development.ini` and `php-production.ini` to enable  `extension=php_openssl.dll`. I made a copy of `php.ini` using the production ini file. I also added `d:\php` to the windows `PATH` and rebooted.

When I point the Composer installation to `d:\php\php.exe` it fails with `openssl` is not enabled. What am I missing? I do not want to install WAMP if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK got it working. What I did ([I got some hints from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178980/native-php-5-6-openssl-composer-phar-failed-to-enable-crypto-on-windows)). I first downloaded the following file:

```
http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

and saved it in my `d:\php` folder

I then edited the newly created php.ini, removed comment and changed the following lines:

```
extension_dir = "d:\php\ext"
openssl.cafile="d:\php\cacert.pem"
openssl.capath="d:\php"
```

Composer then installed OK.