# Composer Error trying to update packages

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, https, composer-php

i want to download packages on my work PC (And is behind a proxy). I getting this error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: 
>   error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
>   Failed to enable crypto
>   failed to open stream: operation failed

I did php composer.phar diag, this is the output:

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking HTTP proxy: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri: OK
Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri: FAIL
Unable to assess the situation, maybe github is down (The "https://api.github.com/repos/Seldaek/jsonlint/zipball/1.0.0" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed)
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: 


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                       
  The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:  
  error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol                                                            
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                        
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Hope that someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: PS: I Read this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268093/composer-cannot-download-files) but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you checked out this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178980/native-php-5-6-openssl-composer-phar-failed-to-enable-crypto-on-windows

Comment: Hi, i made some changes and now I got this error:
Checking http connectivity: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "gcaserotto" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Answer (score -1):

> run the following  command without sudo :

```
composer update
```